# calling stored procedure from classic asp page - not working

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I created a stored procedure that works find when executed in sql server management studio but when I call it from the web page it and actually try to use the form it does not work. I think I am overlooking something or over thinking something.

SQL:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ASSET_insert]
 @iproduct varchar(55),
 @imanufact varchar (55),
 @itype varchar (30),
 @ipart_num varchar(50),
 @iversion varchar(50),
 @iprice float,
 @iwarranty varchar(30),
 @isupport varchar(12),
 @imaintenanc varchar(30),
 @icontact varchar(30),
 @icomments text, 
 @inextproduct_id int,
 @iVENDOR varchar(50)

 AS
  BEGIN       
    SET NOCOUNT ON    


set   @inextproduct_id =(select top 1 nextidvalue from TI_IdGenerator where TableName='PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID')
set   @inextproduct_id = @inextproduct_id + 1
update TI_IdGenerator set NextIdValue = @inextproduct_id where TableName='PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID'


-- ADD the Product type from ProdType - allows us to get the product type and connect to             product. // works but may need to connect to AssetTup

--declare @itype varchar (30)
select @itype=p.AssetType from IN_AssetType p where p.AssetTypeId=@itype


-- Get some of the info we need // Getting the  information form the AssetType 
select @itype = a.AssetType from IN_AssetType a where a.AssetTypeId=@itype 

-- Get more.// Get Vendor Information  - allows us to get create drop-down box 
declare @iVENDOR varchar(50)
select  @iVENDOR=v.COMPANY  from VENDOR v where v.ID=@iVENDOR



--INSERT  into the web inventory form iTemplates into the PRODUCT  
INSERT INTO  PRODUCT  (PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT,MANUFACT,TYPE,PART_NUM,VERSION,VENDOR,PRICE,WARRANTY,SUPPORT,MAINTENANC,CONTACT,COMMENTS)
VALUES(@inextproduct_id,@iPRODUCT,@iMANUFACT,@itype,@iPART_NUM,@iVERSION,@iVENDOR,@iPRICE,@iWARRANTY,@iSUPPORT,@iMAINTENANC,@iCONTACT,@iCOMMENTS)

Return @inextproduct_id

END
```

CODE USED TO CALL stored procedure

```vbs
newproduct_name=Request.Form("iproduct")
newmanufacture_name=Request.Form("imanufact")
newproudct_partnum=Request.Form("ipart_num")
newproduct_version=Request.Form("iversion")
newproduct_price=Request.Form("iprice")
newproudct_warranty=Request.Form("iwarranty")
newproduct_support= Request.Form("isupport")
newproduct_maintenanc= Request.Form("imaintenanc")  
newproduct_contact= Request.Form("icontact")  
newproduct_comments= Request.Form("icomments ")   


  if request.form("submit")="addnewproduct " then    'Add product to the Trackit Database into the PRODUCT 
  sqltext="EXEC Asset_insert " 
        sqltext=sqltext & cstr(inextproduct_id) & "," 
        sqltext=sqltext & cstr(product_id) & "," 
        sqltext=sqltext & cstr(vendor_id) & "," 
        sqltext=sqltext & cstr(assetTypeId) & "," 
  sqltext=sqltext & "'" & newproduct_name & "'"  & ","
        sqltext=sqltext & "'" & newmanufacture_name & "'"  & "," 
        sqltext=sqltext & "'" & newproudct_partnum & "'"  & ","
        sqltext=sqltext & "'" & newproduct_version  & "'"  & ","
        sqltext=sqltext & "'" & newproduct_price  & "'"  & ","
        sqltext=sqltext & "'" & newproudct_warranty & "'"  & ","
        sqltext=sqltext & "'" & newproduct_support & "'"  & ","
        sqltext=sqltext & "'" & newproduct_MAINTENANC & "'"  & ","
        sqltext=sqltext & "'" & newproduct_contact & "'"  & ","
        sqltext=sqltext & "'" & newproduct_comments & "'"  
  'response.write("<br>" & sqltext)
        set rsTrack=connTrack.Execute(sqlText)

        end if
```

HTML CODE That it is being used is as follows

```
<body onLoad="self.focus();document.form2.product.focus();" >
   <FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="" id="form2" name="form2" target="_self">
      <table  title="Add New Product " bgcolor="DarkTurquoise">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>
                  Product
               </th>
               <th>
                  Manufacture
               </th>
               <th>
                  Select Type
               </th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <input tabindex="3" type="text" name="iproduct" id=iproduct   />
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input tabindex="4" type="text" name="imanufact"id=imanufact    />
               </td>
               <td>
                  <%=ASSETNAME%>
               </td>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>
                  Part Number
               </th>
               <th>
                  Version
               </th>
               <th>
                  Vendor
               </th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <td>
            <input tabindex="5" type="text" name="ipart_num" id=ipart_num  />
         </td>
         <td>
            <input tabindex="6" type="text" name="iversion" id=iversion />
         </td>
         <td>
            <%=displayown%>
         </td>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>
                  Price
               </th>
               <th>
                  Support #
               </th>
               <th>
                  Maintenance
               </th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <td>
            <input tabindex="7" type="text" name="iprice" id=iprice/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <input tabindex="8" type="text" name="isupport" id=isupport/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <input tabindex="9" type="text" name="imaintenanc" id=imaintenanc/>
         </td>
         </tr>
         </tbody>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>
                  Warranty: 
               </th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <td>
            <input tabindex="10" type="text" name="iwarranty" id=iwarranty  onclick="JACS.show(document.getElementById('iwarranty'),event);" value="
               <%=iwarranty%>
               " >
         </td>
         <tr>
         <tr>
            <th>
               Contact (Telephone Number): 
            </th>
         </tr>
         <td>
            <input tabindex="11" type="text" name="icontact" id=icontact />
         </td>
         <br />
         <tr>
            <th>
               Comments:  
            </th>
         </tr>
         <td>
            <input tabindex="12" type="text" name="icomments" id=icomments  />
         </td>
         </tr>
         <td>
            <input TYPE="submit" NAME="addnewproduct" VALUE="Add Product" ID=addnewproduct  />
            <br />
         </td>
         <br />
         <td>
            <input type= button onclick='history.go(0)' name="refresh" value="Refresh" />
            <br />
         </td>
      </table>
   </FORM>
```

Comment: Where's the code you use to call the stored procedure?

Comment: oops forgot that - just added it to the question

Comment: If you add the parameter names for each one to the execute statement, does that work? Example: `sqltext = sqltext & "@iproduct = '" & cstr(inextproduct_id) & "',"`

Comment: I will try and let you know

Comment: What error exactly do you get?

Comment: There could be all sorts of reasons this isn't working and mainly due to the approach you are taking. Building a query string like that to execute the query means you have to handle apostrophes (`'`) for varchar and nvarchar values. Also this approach leaves you open to [SQL Injecton Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), consider using `ADODB.Command` and create parameters for your inputs, there are lots of examples of this approach on SO. The technique is called "Parametrised Queries".

Comment: There is no error, it just won't insert. I did try the way j.f. said but again it doesn't actualy insert into the sql table.

Comment: I have two different forms the first one works with the query I created for it. The second one, which I am asking for help here doesn't.

Comment: so i took a lot of the fields out and wanted to know if it was something specific and it said this Incorrect syntax near ',' Line 186. When I look at line 186 it's this 'set rsTrack=connTrack.Execute(sqlText)' code there. I hex it out and the page won't break but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you check for

```
if request.form("submit") = "addnewproduct " then
```

you should check for (without space)

```
if request.form("submit") = "addnewproduct" then
```

But, your code is very vulnerable to bug and SQL Injection.  You should do at least

1 - Validate id ARE integer before using in the query :

```
if not isnumeric(inextproduct_id) then inextproduct_id = 0
sqltext = sqltext & cstr(inextproduct_id) & ","
```

2 - Double quote your string variable :

```
sqltext = sqltext & "'" & replace(newmanufacture_name, "'", "''") & "'"  & ","
```